# UIView is being displayed in Simulator, but not on device itself

Tags: ipad, uiview, ios-simulator

In my app I display an UIView (let's call it "InsideV") which is embedded in another UIView (let's call it "OutsideV"). OutsideV will be displayed throughout the entire time the app is running, InsideV will change due to user actions. (Imagine a book: OutsideV is the cover, InsideV is the currently displayed page).

Now here's my problem: Whereas all's fine when running the app on the simulator, InsideV won't be displayed when the app is running on the device itself.

I have already checked the spelling and I'm sure that this is not causing the problem. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Technical data:
XCode 3.2.4
iOS: 3.2/4.1

Comment: Problem solved: It actually has been a spelling problem: the view had to display a png-file; the file's name had been hard coded in the app and (wait for it!) the hard coded name differed from the actual name by one letter: a 'p' (code) instead of a 'P' (actual file name).